# I got an error message during using libmms, what does that mean?

Tags: iphone, networking, network-programming, stream, mms

I am new in libmms and I am trying to make Iphone app that streams mms radio.

But I got an error message and do not yet figure out why.

```
Could not read packet header: Undefined error: 0
***LOG:*** -- libmms: failed to read mms packet header
```

And this is the code I used.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSString *stringUri = @"mms://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/2011-1/NOON/0506.wma";
    NSString *stringHost = @"xxx.xxx.xx.xxx";
    NSString *scheme = @"mms";
    id data;
    int bandwidth = 3000000;
    mmsx_connect (mms_io, &data, [stringUri UTF8String], [stringHost UTF8String],     [stringUri UTF8String], NULL, NULL,[scheme UTF8String] , bandwidth);

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

The thing I have to mention is that mmsx_connect's first parameter's type is mms_io_t and I did just made interface not implimetation

this is the definition of type mms_io_t

```
typedef struct
{
  mms_io_select_func select;
  void *select_data;
  mms_io_read_func read;
  void *read_data;
  mms_io_write_func write;
  void *write_data;
  mms_io_tcp_connect_func connect;
  void *connect_data;
} mms_io_t;
```

please help me. I am new in libmms, and I can't find useful documents about it.
Any comment and help is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
mmsx_connect (mms_io, &data, [stringUri UTF8String], [stringHost UTF8String],     [stringUri UTF8String], NULL, NULL,[scheme UTF8String] , bandwidth);
```

You should pass parameter to `const char *uri` (fifth parameter) -> @"/2011-1/NOON/0506.wma".
Not `[stringUri UTF8String]`.
And it works fine.